# Springboot Scheduled Trigger on Entity Existence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a function in spring boot that checks every 10th of a second (100 ms) for any existing entity in a JPA SQL database, and processes the requested actions, and deletes the entity once the actions have been completed. Problem is, checking the db every 100ms is very memory intensive, expensive, and wasteful, and has caused crashes before (because I am running this on a free server, and maxes out the memory). I was wondering, is there a method similar to `@scheduled` that triggers the method if a db table holds any rows (basically, if `exampleRepository.findAll()` does not return `null`, then my method runs)?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple of options you could try.

1. If your "processing" is just another database action, inserting/updating another table, then why don't you give database triggers a try?
2. You might benefit from an event-driven architecture, use a message queue or expose an API in your service which will consume the data directly. Schedulers are generally the last resort in such cases.
3. The out of memory issue might not be because of limited memory but the way you are retrieving the data from the database. Instead of loading all the data at once use smaller chunks and do batch processing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! My items are already batched :), and because my code is built on a closed sourced codebase of others, unfortunately, API processing will not be possible. I will definitely try db triggers a shot!